# How to get the category name for a distribution from a WEKA classifier in java code

Tags: java, weka

I have a simple naive bayes classifier from WEKA. I'm using a directory structure and reading it in via the TextDirectoryLoader. The Directory structure is

```
Training_Data
     Spam (folder)
         text files
     Ham (folder)
         text files
```

I can get the distributions like this

```
for(Instance i: testInstances){

    double [] distributions = classifier.distributionForInstance(i);
    for(double d : distributions)
        System.out.println(d);
}
```

what I want to do is get the category name to go along side the distribution so I can print it out like so

```
System.out.println("Category: "+/*something to get the category name*/+ ":"+ d);
```

I've been looking around for hours now and can't figure out how to do it. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `instance.classAttribute().value(valIndex)` where `valIndex` is the index of the category:

```
for(Instance i: testInstances){
  double [] distributions = classifier.distributionForInstance(i);
  for(int index = 0; index < distributions.length; index++)
      System.out.println(i.classAttribute().value(index) + ": " + distributions[index]);
}
```